# How to serialize big objects in .NET? (OutOfMemory Exceptions)

Tags: .net, memory, serialization, out-of-memory

I'm using serialization for "save" feature in my application. But when the data is too big (15+ MB) I'm starting to get OutOfMemory exceptions.

I've got so many objects and they are connected with other little objects, I think this is causing too much processing power and data held in the memory.

My code is based on this, almost same:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/TreeViewDataAccess.aspx

**Edit :**

1. I don't use custom serialization, it's all done by [Serialization] attributes. Excluding some fields.
2. I serialize so many objects and custom classes. Includes Dictionary, structures and bunch of other stuff.
3. I serialize it into a file.
4. I use XmlSerializer

*P.S. I've got 4 GB physical memory.*

**Solution**

Thanks to answers, my problem was found to be with XmlSerializer and I've got rid of it. Binary serialization is working just fine with the data I've got.

Comment: What type of object is it? And what serialization framework are you using? Is the data a tree? or a graph? (i.e. is there more than one route to any object)?

Comment: It's so many linked objects including lots of custom classes as well as a treeview :)

Comment: I'm not using a special framework using .NET serialization (.NET Framework 2.0).

Comment: but are they *cross* linked... this has impact...

Comment: Good question, they might actually. I've lost track of them. Do .NET duplicate them instead of figuring out links?

Comment: That depends on the other question I asked: what serialization framework are you using? BinaryFormatter? XmlSerializer? DataContractSerializer? JSON? etc?

Comment: Sorry, now I see. It's BinaryFormatter

Comment: How about posting an example of your serialization code?

Comment: I've looked up again and actual exception was in the XmlSerializer, I use both of them. first XmlSerializer for Treeview then normal serilization for the rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15MB shouldn't give you an OOM.

If the data is tree-like (rather than a full graph), you might consider a serializer like [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net); as well as using Google's very efficient (both speed and memory) binary "protocol buffers" format, it benefits from not having to do reference tracking (required for graphs) - which means it only has to worry about data once (twice if it has to get buffered).

However, this requires different markup to your classes (or at least, an "opt in") - and it won't handle full graphs. But it is there, and free...

Comment: I've just checked the code actual exception was happening in the XmlSerializer - that part of the code is based on this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/TreeViewDataAccess.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. The reason is that .NET
serialization does not scale.

I solved the problem by using Simon Hewitt's excellent open
source library, see *[Optimizing Serialization in .NET - part
2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16017/Optimizing-Serialization-in-NET-part)*.

Besides dramatically reducing memory usage it is also much
faster. Similar to the article I got a speed-up of 20 times.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, XmlSerializer ignores the SerializableAttribute attributes. They're used only by the formatting classes (BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter).

I wouldn't serialize using the XmlSerializer, and especially not a combination of XmlSerializer and BinaryFormatter.

I would simply try to serialize everything using the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: I think that makes sense. I was using it because someone already wrote the code for persistent Treeview storage. Anyway I'll try to replace with Binaryformatter as well, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own serialization routines and see if you can gain any performance benefits by hand-tailoring your serialization process. For more details, see the [MSDN page on Custom Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give us a little more detail about how the serialization is made. Do you use a custom serialization ? Or do you just use the built-in [Serialization] attribute ?

I think that a good way for you to handle this is to try to do your custom serialization logic and only serialize only what you need, it can't go to 4GB, anyway it also depends on how much memeory your application has assigned.

Comment: .NET manages the memory, right? So I don't have control over it. I assume if the app goes more than 1GB app generally gets unstable. Is there anyway to allocate more memory to my app?

Comment: @Slough - well, you could go to x64 and shove in a ton of memory; but this feels like it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With all the approaches that are mentioned here, the ease of dumping big objects to disk and recovering is lost. Also these support only dump data types, So you can't dump reference types as easily as you could with BinaryFormatter.

Also doing compression using [gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) or [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) before binary formatting of large objects actually move the size above 16 MB to something like 32 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You could Download [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) Library which works in my project more than 100 MB data's serialization and deserialization.

For Serialization you can work like

If you have Object use TextWriter

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText("LocalJsonFile.json"))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter , yourObject);
}
```

If you have string use StringWriter

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

  using(JsonWriter textWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
  {
     var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
     serializer.Serialize(textWriter, yourObject);
  }
```

This may work for you.