# Arithmetic overflow in C# when attempting to serialize very large object

Tags: c#, json

I have an issue regarding the JsonSerialization library under System.Text.Json.Serialization.

Effectively, I have a REALLY massive object I need to store for later, and there isn't really a way to make it smaller. It is the entire multi-genome network that makes up my homemade over thousands of nodes per genome, all with their own unique data, so obviously it's going to be massive in data usage.

So, I just do "JsonSerialization.Serialize(myAINetworkObject)", and after awhile of thinking and about 1GB of RAM usage (Completely understandable), it just crashes out with the following message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at System.Text.Json.PooledByteBufferWriter.CheckAndResizeBuffer(Int32 sizeHint)
   at System.Text.Json.PooledByteBufferWriter.GetMemory(Int32 sizeHint)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter.Grow(Int32 requiredSize)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter.WriteNumberValueMinimized(Single value)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter.WriteNumberValue(Single value)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(PooledByteBufferWriter output, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCoreString(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at NEAT_AI.Network.saveNetwork2(Network myself) in C:\Users\aj200\Documents\GitHub\My-Projects\My-Projects\Completed Projects\C# NEAT AI\NEAT_AI.cs:line 708
   at WebAPIClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\aj200\Documents\GitHub\My-Projects\My-Projects\Completed Projects\C# NEAT AI\Program.cs:line 65
```

I could post the entire code of what I'm running here, but I would prefer to keep my months of work private as much as possible.

So, effectively my question is: "Is there any way I can increase the amount of data that the default JSONSerialization library can handle without crashing". I can split the network into "Basic network data", and seperate files for each genome individually, but that would take a fair bit of work.

I am aware that the JSONSerialization library was probably never designed to handle multi-GB objects, and was never expected to come across anything that large.

As an alternative, I am willing to physically edit the JSONSerialization library to use Int64 instead of Int32 for it's variables, but I want to know if such a thing is worth the effort, or if it would even help at all.

Kind regards,
Andrey

Comment: An option would be to serialize to another format than JSON. I'm thinking about protobuf for instance, which is compressed. Very related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709399/how-to-serialize-big-objects-in-net-outofmemory-exceptions

Comment: The problem is a 2GB string buffer. Don't use a string api, use a stream, I assume to a file. eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializeasync?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializeAsync_System_IO_Stream_System_Object_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: Also, be careful with how you build your object graph, so that you aren't writing multiple copies of the same object.

Comment: When serializing to a string, `System.Text.Json` first writes utf8 bytes to a [`PooledByteBufferWriter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Text/Json/PooledByteBufferWriter.cs) then later converts that to a `string`.  Your problem is that `PooledByteBufferWriter` is backed by an array, and your JSON is so huge you overflow the .Net maximum array size of 2 GB.  You could try setting [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39025934) to see if that resolves the problem...

Comment: 2 gigs of json anything is likely a sign you are doing something wrong. Consider a relational or nosql database

Comment: ... but even if `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` allows you to fully write your JSON to a `PooledByteBufferWriter` you will likely hit the .Net maximum string length when that is converted to a utf16 `string`.  You will need to adopt a different approach using streams -- and not `MemoryStream` which is also backed by an array. You will need to use a `FileStream` or maybe [`Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream).  Note that `System.Text.Json` only supports **`async`** serialization to streams so you may need to rewrite some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to everyone who offered solutions. I tried some of the other JSON formatters, but none of them were quite what I was looking for. However, I did in the end manage to create a custom save function that mimics how JSON does things.

Effectively, it's not saving all of this into one file (Hence, no limitations really). It saves each object as a folder on my PC, then each of it's properties are in a file next to any folder that might also be there if I had a list of objects inside this object. AKA, I've created a physical file version of how JSON works.

So for example an object structure like the following like this (pseudo code):

```
Network {
 string saveData;
 List<Genome>();
}

Genome {
 string someOtherData;
 List<Node>();
}

Node {
 int ID;
 enum node_type;
 int current_weight;
}
```

Would look like this:

```
/Network/genomeObject1/genomeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject1/Nodes/Node ID 1/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject1/Nodes/Node ID 2/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject1/Nodes/Node ID 3/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject1/Nodes/Node ID 4/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject2/genomeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject2/Nodes/Node ID 1/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject2/Nodes/Node ID 2/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject2/Nodes/Node ID 3/nodeProperties.txt
/Network/genomeObject2/Nodes/Node ID 4/nodeProperties.txt
etc
```

It's a very custom solution, and I would have liked a simple serialization script or something, but alas it works anyways. If I can get it to handle any serializable data, I might drop the code down sometime!

Thankyou all for helping me!

Comment: For anyone looking to do something similar to me. I BEG OF YOU do not use JSON formatting. If possible, use CSV format. Not only is it SOOOO much easier to work with (And you don't even need a library to use it it's that simple), but it also tends to be much smaller too. Looking back on this, my decision to use JSON formatting was a poor one, and were I to do this again, I'd just use CSV from the very start